# Quarkus + keycloak - HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

Tags: keycloak, quarkus, quarkus-rest-client

I was trying out **Quarkus** security integration with **keycloak**

Here is my rest endpoints

```
@Path("/jwt")
@RequestScoped
public class JWTRestController {

    @Inject
    @Claim(standard = Claims.preferred_username)
    Optional<JsonString> currentUsername;

    @GET
    @Path("/user")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @RolesAllowed({"user"})
    public String userData() {
        return "data for user ";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/admin")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @RolesAllowed({"admin"})
    public String adminData() {
        return "data for admin ";
    }

}
```

My application properties

```
# Configuration file
quarkus.http.port=8082

# MP-JWT Config
mp.jwt.verify.publickey.location=http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/demo/protocol/openid-connect/certs
mp.jwt.verify.issuer=http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/demo
quarkus.smallrye-jwt.auth-mechanism=MP-JWT
quarkus.smallrye-jwt.realmName=quarkus-keycloak-demo
quarkus.smallrye-jwt.enabled=true
```

I have running instance of **keycloak** on my local development machine on port 8180
I have done all the per-requisite for keycloak and created realm, user, roles

I am able to get token from keycloak as follow -

```
export access_token=$(\
    curl -X POST http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/demo/protocol/openid-connect/token \
    --user demo-client:e0da2ad7-5f4c-49b3-ae54-dbd7a28d532a \
    -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
    -d 'username=user&password=user&grant_type=password' | jq --raw-output '.access_token' \
 )
```

But here is problem when try to access the rest point **/jwt/user**

```
curl -v -H "Authorization: Bearer $access_token" http://localhost:8082/jwt/user
```

**It results in**

```
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Content-Length: 9
< Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
Forbidden* Closing connection 0
```

Here is token details (I user jwt.io debugger to look inside the token )

[image]

Anyhelp would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Please use quarkus-oidc, follow https://quarkus.io/guides/security-openid-connect for the service applications which accept the bearer tokens

Answer (score 0):

In the Keycloak, the role admin must be assigned to the demo-client.

About Quarkus JWT RBAC, the extension expects a token having a "groups" claim.

There is a Quarkus JWT configuration used to map a different claim for roles (in this case realm_access/roles):

smallrye.jwt.path.groups="realm_access/roles"